# Как перемещать объекты по дуге в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть меню.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, что-бы при нажатии на левый чёрный круг (UI-Buttons), назовём его "Настройки", из него плавно выезжали две новые кнопки по дуге и останавливались в заданной мною позиции (Цветами показал траектории кнопок и места остановок).

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте анимтор и анимацию.
В аниматора сделайте этим кнопкам две анимации - в одном они летят направо, в другом налево.

Переход между ними зависит от флага "IsOpen". Из скрипта по нажатию кнопки передёргиваете флаг. В итоге при нажатии кнопки - начнёт проигрываться анимация, либо показа, либо скрывания. Это самый простой вариант.